# Cannot get wordpress API to work with React

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, rest

First, thank you for any help. I'm new to React and come from a PHP/Wordpress background.

I'm trying to add the items from a WordPress API call to a state, but when I try to access the information from the API call it keeps giving me errors of undefined.

Here is my code, I hope someone has dealt with this before and can help out.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from 'react'

//Templates
import App from '../App';


class FaqPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            faqs: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://starcsystems.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/12844")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    faqs: result.faqs
                });
                console.log(result);
            },
            // Note: it's important to handle errors here
            // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
            // exceptions from actual bugs in components.


            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error
                });
            }
        )
    }

    render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, faqs } = this.state;
        if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Value Run</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>{this.state.faqs.id}</li>
                </ul>
                <p>Value After Run</p>
            </div>
        );
        }
    }
}

export default FaqPanel;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no **faqs** as key in the data.

```
 (result) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        faqs: result <---- Just put it like this
  });
```

Just to make sure, you don't get a type error.

```
<ul>
  <li>{this.state.faqs && this.state.faqs.id}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Niraj! I did end up implementing it and it is a good check to not have the whole program fail. You're correct that faqs doesn't work correctly because it isn't in the data requested. I put that url as a place holder because I'm actually doing development on my local and couldn't really think of a way to show the data.

I can't seem to render the data from an array, whenever I try to use map it ends up giving me an error faqs.map is not a function.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from 'react'

//Templates
import App from '../App';


class FaqPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            faqs: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/wp-react-mgb/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/9")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    faqs: result
                });
            },
            // Note: it's important to handle errors here
            // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
            // exceptions from actual bugs in components.


            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error
                });
            }
        )
    }

    render() {

        const { error, isLoaded, faqs } = this.state;
        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
            return (

                <div>
                    <p>Value Run</p>
                    {console.log('this is the faqs')}
                    {console.log(faqs)}
                    <p>{this.state.faqs && this.state.faqs.acf.modified_gmt}</p>
                    {/* {faqs.map(function(faq, index) {
                        return <li>{faq.faq_question[index]}</li>;
                    })} */}

                    {faqs.map(function (value, index) {
                        return <p key={index}>{value}</p>
                    })}
                    <p>Value After Run</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default FaqPanel;
```

That is my whole new code and below is the console.log for the result from the API call.

Thanks again for taking a look, it is greatly appreciated!
-Darrel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1DKX.png)